# Is it OK to stutter while saying brachot?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing

Is it halachically acceptable to repeat words due to stuttering while saying a Bracha, as long as all the words are said?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already?

Comment: What's the alternative, not saying a brocha?

Comment: Yes, but I didn’t get a satisfying answer.

Comment: @RaphaelChilungu That's not a reason to repost. If it didn't get an answer, maybe no one has an answer. Or maybe the question needs improvement. You can always edit it to add more detail, which will also bump the question.